# merge observables don't get the value of the second observable

Tags: angular, merge, observable, rxjs6

i have a little problem with this code :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Subject, merge } from 'rxjs';
import { scan, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { boatsList } from 'src/app/shared/mocks/boats.mock';
import { CatamaranModel } from 'src/app/shared/models/catamaran.model';
import { SailBoatModel } from 'src/app/shared/models/sail-boat.model';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class BoatListService {

  private boatListInitSubject: BehaviorSubject<(CatamaranModel|SailBoatModel)[]> = new BehaviorSubject(boatsList);
  boatListInit$ = this.boatListInitSubject.asObservable();

  private addedBoatSubject: Subject<(CatamaranModel|SailBoatModel)> = new Subject();
  addedBoat$ = this.addedBoatSubject.asObservable();

  boatList$ = merge(
    this.boatListInit$,
    this.addedBoat$
  )
    .pipe(
      scan((acc: (CatamaranModel|SailBoatModel)[], value: CatamaranModel|SailBoatModel) => [...acc, value])
    );

  constructor() {
  }

  addBoat(boat: CatamaranModel | SailBoatModel){
    this.addedBoatSubject.next(boat);
  }
}
```

The problem is in my merge

```
 boatList$ = merge(
    this.boatListInit$,
    this.addedBoat$
  )
    .pipe(
      scan((acc: (CatamaranModel|SailBoatModel)[], value: CatamaranModel|SailBoatModel) => [...acc, value])
    );
```

I use this merge to had a new object to my collection but the object in the addedBoat$ is never added to the list and i don't know why.
When i do a map instead of the scan, i don't find the result of this.addedBoat$.

If i subscribe to this.addedBoat$ and i launch the addBoat function, i have the good object.

Do i make a bad use of the merge?

Comment: do you get any errors with your code?

Comment: I had no error, i just don't retrieve the value of this.addedBoat$

Comment: i believe you are getting an error, that is why observable stops

Comment: i put a catchError but i catch no error. The problem is not that i get nothing, the merge return just the value of the first observable, i don't even pass in the scan (console.log in it displays nothing)

Comment: In fact, the merge is working well, the problem is my boatList$ variable, when i call it, it don't subscribe. I think i have a more obvious error to find ^^

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line

private addedBoatSubject: Subject<(CatamaranModel|SailBoatModel)> = new Subject();

to

private addedBoatSubject: BehaviourSubject<(CatamaranModel|SailBoatModel)> = new BehaviourSubject(your desired value);

Answer (score -1):

you should use combineLatest in this scenario.....change your call accordingly:

```
import { combineLatest} from 'rxjs';

boatList$ = combineLatest(
    this.boatListInit$,
    this.addedBoat$
  )
    .pipe(
      scan((acc: (CatamaranModel|SailBoatModel)[], value: CatamaranModel|SailBoatModel) => [...acc, value])
    );
```